# ModalBottomSheetLayout content is not get centered, as well as sheet content

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, centering, android-bottomsheetdialog

Based on what was answered in this question ([Open ModalSheetLayout on TextField focus instead of Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73391798/open-modalsheetlayout-on-textfield-focus-instead-of-keyboard/73392149)) and the exchange of comments I did with @Abhimanyu, I was able to get the ModalBottomSheetLayout to appear when I click on one of the TextFields, however I encountered two more problems. I can't center what's in the content, nor can I center the content that's inside the sheet content. Can anyone help me understand why?

Here is a print of what is happening and my code:

[image]

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Preview
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen() {
    var profileModalBottomSheetType by remember { mutableStateOf(ProfileModalBottomSheetType.NONE) }
    val modalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    if (modalBottomSheetState.currentValue != ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden) {
        DisposableEffect(Unit) {
            onDispose {
                profileModalBottomSheetType = ProfileModalBottomSheetType.NONE
            }
        }
    }

    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 13.dp, topEnd = 13.dp),
        sheetContent = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = 10.dp)
                    .height(10.dp)
                    .width(100.dp)
                    .background(
                        color = Color.LightGray,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
                    )
            )

            when (profileModalBottomSheetType) {
                ProfileModalBottomSheetType.SELECT_RATE -> {
                    SelectRateModalBottomSheet(listOf("Exact Rate", "Range"))
                }
                else -> {}
            }
        }
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(320.dp)
        ) {
            item {
                HeightSpacer(40.dp)

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_clearjobs_logo_2x),
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                }

                HeightSpacer(47.dp)

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(320.dp)
                        .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Profile Light Title",
                        style = TextStyle32Light,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                    )

                    Text(
                        text = "Profile Bold Title",
                        style = TextStyle32Bold,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                    )
                }

                HeightSpacer(47.dp)

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                                topStart = 13.dp,
                                topEnd = 13.dp
                            ), color = Color.White
                        )
                        .padding(bottom = 140.dp)
                        .width(320.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(id = R.string.your_profile),
                        style = TextStyle28Bold,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(
                            top = 40.dp,
                            start = 20.dp,
                            bottom = 30.dp
                        )
                    )

                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(id = R.string.salary_range),
                        style = TextStyle28Bold,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(
                            top = 40.dp,
                            start = 20.dp,
                            bottom = 30.dp
                        )
                    )

                    Box {
                        LightBlueBorderTextField(
                            title = "Rate",
                            initialState = "Exact Rate",
                            textFieldTextStyle = TextStyle16BlackOpacity50Normal,
                            enabled = false
                        ) { innerTextField ->
                            Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                                Box(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .weight(1f)
                                        .padding(start = Dimen10)
                                ) {
                                    innerTextField()
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .matchParentSize()
                                .alpha(0f)
                                .clickable(
                                    onClick = {
                                        profileModalBottomSheetType =
                                            ProfileModalBottomSheetType.SELECT_RATE
                                        toggleModalBottomSheetState(
                                            coroutineScope = coroutineScope,
                                            modalBottomSheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
                                        )
                                    }
                                )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SelectRateModalBottomSheet(options: List<String>) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(
            start = 20.dp,
            end = 20.dp,
            top = 15.dp,
            bottom = 15.dp
        )
    ) {
        items(options.size) { optionIndex ->
            val option = options[optionIndex]

            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp, bottom = 15.dp)
            ) {
                Box(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                    Text(text = option, style = TextStyle16BlackOpacity50Normal)
                }

                RadioButton(
                    selected = false,
                    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(20.dp)
                        .height(20.dp)
                )
            }

            if (optionIndex != options.lastIndex) {
                Divider(color = Color.DarkGray, thickness = 1.dp)
                HeightSpacer(dimen = 15.dp)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun HeightSpacer(dimen: Dp) {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(dimen))
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun LightBlueBorderTextField(
    title: String = "",
    initialState: String = "",
    textFieldTextStyle: TextStyle = TextStyle18Normal,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    decorationBox: @Composable (innerTextField: @Composable () -> Unit) -> Unit = { innerTextField ->
        Box(
            Modifier.padding(start = Dimen10),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
        ) {
            innerTextField()
        }
    }
) {
    Column {
        val state = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(initialState)) }

        if (title.isNotEmpty()) {
            Text(
                text = title,
                style = TextStyle16BlackBold,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(
                    top = Dimen40,
                    start = Dimen30,
                    bottom = Dimen10
                )
            )
        } else {
            HeightSpacer(Dimen40)
        }

        CustomTextField(
            state = state,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(Dimen45)
                .padding(start = Dimen20, end = Dimen20)
                .border(
                    width = Dimen1,
                    color = LightBlue,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(Dimen13)
                )
                .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(Dimen13))
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            textStyle = textFieldTextStyle,
            decorationBox = decorationBox,
            enabled = enabled
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomTextField(
    state: MutableState<TextFieldValue>,
    modifier: Modifier,
    textStyle: TextStyle = TextStyle18Normal,
    decorationBox: @Composable (innerTextField: @Composable () -> Unit) -> Unit,
    enabled: Boolean = true
) {
    BasicTextField(
        modifier = modifier,
        value = state.value,
        onValueChange = { value -> state.value = value },
        singleLine = true,
        textStyle = textStyle,
        decorationBox = decorationBox,
        enabled = enabled
    )
}

@ExperimentalMaterialApi
fun toggleModalBottomSheetState(
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    modalBottomSheetState: ModalBottomSheetState,
    action: (() -> Unit)? = null,
) {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        if (!modalBottomSheetState.isAnimationRunning) {
            if (modalBottomSheetState.isVisible) {
                modalBottomSheetState.hide()
            } else {
                modalBottomSheetState.show()
            }
        }
        action?.invoke()
    }
}

internal enum class ProfileModalBottomSheetType {
    NONE,
    SELECT_JOB_KEYWORDS,
    SELECT_WORK_LOCATIONS,
    SELECT_TAGS,
    SELECT_RATE,
    SELECT_SALARY_PERIOD
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minified reproducible example that can be run in isolation. The given code has `BottomSheetBackHandler`, a lot of Dimens, `ScreenHeader`, etc. With this, I can not run the app to debug the issue.

Comment: Hi @Abhimanyu ! You are right, my bad. I updated the code. You should be able to look at that now.

Comment: Did a new updated to change some more Dimens @Abhimanyu

Comment: Please add code for `HeightSpacer`, `toggleModalBottomSheetState` and `LightBlueBorderTextField` as well.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Done, I forgot that ones, sorry.

Comment: Hi @Abhimanyu, were you able to run the code?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by putting all the ModalBottomSheet content inside a Box with Modifier.fillMaxSize() and the contentAlignment = Alignment.Center. See my code below:

```
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = Dimen13, topEnd = Dimen13),
        sheetContent = {
            JobDetailsModalBottomSheet(modalBottomSheetType, jobClicked) {
                modalBottomSheetType = JobOpeningsScreenModalBottomSheetType.NONE
                toggleModalBottomSheetState(
                    coroutineScope = coroutineScope,
                    modalBottomSheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
                )
            }
        }) {
        Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            // any content
        }
    }
```

I'm not really sure why this doesn't work without Box, but after a few tries, this was the solution I found and it worked.

Comment: The sheet content of ModalBottomSheetLayout is basically a Column that draws top to bottom, so it's impossible to center anything vertically.  That's why you had to add a Box what filled up the whole column.